# Address of 32 bits integer in Modula-2 on a Big Endian architecture

Tags: embedded, endianness, modula-2

I have this line of code in modula-2 on a Big Endian processor :

```
Ptr := ADR(My_32_Bits_Integer)
```

I want to know if Ptr will be equal to the adress of the most significant byte (so the littlest address) or the less significant byte (so the biggest address) ?

Answer (score 2):

The address of a 32 bit number is always that of the byte allocated first. On Big Endian systems, this is the MS byte, on Little Endian it is the LS byte.

Given the 32-bit integer 12345678h, then it will be stored like this:

Big Endian:

```
Offset   Data 
0        12
1        34
2        56
3        78
```

Little Endian:

```
Offset   Data 
0        78
1        56
2        34
3        12
```